# Generating subalgebras of Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a finite dimensional $K$-Lie algebra and let $X$ be a subset of $L$. Ley $Y= \langle X \rangle _{K} $ the linear span of $X$. Also let $v_1,…,v_n $ be a basis of $Y$ and let $Z=\{[v_i , v_j ] : 1\leq i < n \leq n \} $.
I need to show that $Y+\langle Z \rangle _K $ is contained in the subalgebra generated by $X$.

The proof I’m reading says that if $x,y \in Y$, then $ [x,y ] \in \langle X \rangle _{K-\text{alg}} $ but I can’t see why that has to be the case.

Comment: Why do we have $[Y, Y] \subseteq Y$?

Comment: I’m confused whether in the proof it means a Lie subalgebra or just a subalgebra (meaning for $x, y \in Y $ we have $xy \in Y$ but not necessarily $[x,y] \in Y$). Do we need it necessarily to be a Lie subalgebra?

Comment: How is $xy$ defined? There is only one $K$-algebra product, namely $[x,y]$. Similarly, there is no product $v_iv_j$, but only $[v_i,v_j]$.

Comment: That’s a good question. I guess I’m being confused here and mistaking a general $K$-algebra where you would write $xy$ for the product (where the product is just a bilinear map) and so I suppose here the product is the lie bracket which makes sense

Comment: You still have the index typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142931/discussion-between-anonmath101-and-dietrich-burde).